# Videos playing too fast

Tags: video, music

I am not sure if this is a Ubuntu fault but I have Ubuntu setup with LXDE. Just today, I found that videos on YouTube plays too fast. I tried with daily motion, same thing. Then tried to download trailers from apple. I get an error about segmentation fault. Did something go wrong with Ubuntu?

I saw a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42875/fast-video-playback-with-no-sound) then I also noticed that when videos fast forward, theres not sound too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your version of Ubuntu 64-bit? If it is, that is most likely the problem. Adobe has terrible problems when it comes to supporting 64-bit drivers.

Comment: yes its 64bit, I wonder if it will be a waste if I install 32bit? Does 64bit provide any performance or other benefits?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think installing pulseaudio fixed it, or perhaps it was something else'

Answer (score 2):

Here is the thing that worked for me.

Go to System->Preferences->Sound->Hardware

disable the item which is selected in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Flash, it seems to be Flash that is your problem.
If that doesn't work, try downloading the w32 codecs. 
`sudo apt-get install w32codecs`
Sorry I don't have much info, hope it helps though. :)