# MP4 plays too fast

Tags: video, vlc, mp4

I am trying to play an MP4, but it plays too fast, as in fast-forward. The sound track is on time though.
[Existing solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44644/videos-playing-too-fast) don't apply to me.
Should I be able to slow down the frame rate on VLC or do I need to edit the MP4 properties?

As suggested below I tried converting the file with avconv to fix the bug. But the conversion didn't succeed, here is the output:

```
> avconv -i ./Movie.mp4 ./Movie.avi  

avconv version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:00:59 with gcc 4.6.3
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.Movie.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1M4V mp42M4A 
    creation_time   : 2013-10-05 15:38:23
    artist          : 
    album           : 
    comment         : 
    date            : na
    genre           : 
    title           : Movie
  Duration: 01:49:29.89, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1048 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1999 kb/s, 23.53 fps, 23.53 tbr, 23529 tbn, 47.06 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-05 15:38:23
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 47 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-05 15:38:27
[buffer @ 0x9f929e0] w:1280 h:720 pixfmt:yuv420p
Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'ac3', auto-selecting format 'flt'
[ac3 @ 0x9f7c740] invalid bit rate
Output #0, avi, to './Movie.avi':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1M4V mp42M4A 
    creation_time   : 2013-10-05 15:38:23
    artist          : 
    album           : 
    comment         : 
    date            : na
    genre           : 
    title           : Movie
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 23.53 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-05 15:38:23
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, flt, 200 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-05 15:38:27
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mpeg4)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> ac3)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: i'ld just try re-encoding it with ffmpeg/avconv and seeing what happens.  re-encoding should catch stupid play-rate bugs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the <kbd>-</kbd> button in VLC to slow down a video, and the <kbd>+</kbd> to speed it up again.

Comment: Yeah, but that slows down the audio track too..